# Problema com um atributo string de um objeto

Tags: c++, string, orientação-a-objetos

Olá!

Estou tendo um problema com um membro do tipo string do meu objeto. Quando eu faço a atribuição objeto.palavra = "alguma palavra", o programa até compila e roda, mas quando eu imprimo o conteúdo, aparece símbolos totalmente diferentes.

Aqui o codigo main:

```
#include "palavra.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    Palavra p1;
    Palavra p2;

    p1.palavra = "abc";
    p2.palavra = "Olani";

    printf("%s, %s\n", p1.palavra, p2.palavra);

    return(0);
}
```

Palavra.cpp:

```
#include "palavra.h"
#include <iostream>

//passar a arvore
Palavra Palavra::palavrasemelhante(const Palavra& p1, const Palavra& p2)
{
    //se for igual as duas primeiras letras entao sao semelhantes
    if(p1.palavra[0] == p2.palavra[0])
    {
        if(p1.palavra[1] == p2.palavra[1]){
            return (p2);
        }
    }       
    return (p1);
}

const string Palavra::getString()
{
    //retornar palavra para comparação de igual igual
    return (this->palavra);
}

//sobrecarga de operador == para comparar dois objetos da classe Palavra
bool Palavra::operator == (Palavra &p2)
{
    //palavra==p2.getstring ou desse jeitoif ( 0 == strcmp(palavra, p2.getString()))
    if (palavra == p2.getString())
        return (true);

    else
        return (false);

}
```

e Palavra.h:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using std::string;

class Palavra 
{
    private:
        //int tamanho;
        //string palavra;

    public:
        Palavra palavrasemelhante(const Palavra &p1, const Palavra &p2);
        bool operator==(Palavra &p2);
        const string getString();
        string palavra;
};
```

Ao compilar e executar nenhum erro é apontado, mas quando vejo o conteudo fica assim:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Obrigado pela ajuda!

Comment: Uma classe `Palavra` que encapsula um atributo `string palavra` para fazer `palavra.palavra` parece bastante estranho no minimo. Porque não simplificar e utilizar duas `strings` normais ? Isto até evitava ter que definir o operador `==` que acabou complicando ainda mais, e o mesmo para o `tamanho` que já obtem diretamente da `string` com `size()`. Ou seja resumindo, qual o objetivo de toda esta abstração/complicação ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A questão está em que você está a utilizar `printf` para mostrar o que seria uma `string` em C puro, ou seja um `char*`, mas na verdade você tem uma `std::string` e não um `char*`.

Este problema é visível quando compila. Veja o aviso que eu obtenho referente a esta linha:

```
printf("%s, %s\n", p1.palavra, p2.palavra);
```

> ||=== Build: Debug in TestC++ (compiler: GNU GCC Compiler) ===|
>
> ...main.cpp|60|warning: format '%s' expects argument of type 'char*'...
>
> ...main.cpp|60|warning: format '%s' expects argument of type 'char*'...
>
> ||=== Build finished: 0 error(s), 2 warning(s) (0 minute(s), 1 second(s)) ===|

<sup>Minimizei as mensagens do compilador só ao que é relevante</sup>

Consegue resolver mantendo o `printf` com `%s` mas para isso precisar de aceder ao array de chars que está dentro da `std::string` através do método [`c_str`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/c_str/):

```
printf("%s, %s\n", p1.palavra.c_str(), p2.palavra.c_str());
//                             ^---                ^---
```

[Veja a funcionar no Ideone](https://ideone.com/TdqNp3)

Uma abordagem mais em linha com C++ seria utilizar `cout`, pois esse foi desenhado para lidar com `std::string`:

```
cout << p1.palavra << ", " << p2.palavra << endl;
```

[Veja também este exemplo no Ideone](https://ideone.com/ncktUw)

Como nota final, veja o que eu comentei. Você neste momento tem uma classe com vários métodos que literalmente guarda apenas uma `string`, e acaba por estar a replicar lógica que já existe na `string`. Se apenas precisa da palavra então simplifique e use uma `string` normal e crie uma função normal para o `palavrasemelhante`. Dessa forma não só sera mais simples como mais natural.

Comment: Muito Obrigado! Como estou muito acostumado a programar só com C, esqueci desses detalhes do c++. Vou arrumar a classe segundo suas dicas. obrigado novamente!